# manually assign lead in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger UpdateLead on Lead (before insert) {


     Set<Id> LdIdSet = new Set<Id>();
     List<Lead> LdList = [ SELECT Id,Name, OwnerId, Create_Leasing_Call_Task__c,Leasing_Agent__c, Lead_Property_Of_Interest__c FROM Lead WHERE Id IN : LdIdSet];  
     String mySubject;


         for ( Lead ld : Trigger.New ){
            LdIdSet.add ( Ld.Id );
            if (ld.Create_Leasing_Call_Task__c==true)
            {                            
                //    if Create Leasing Task = true
                if ( ld.Lead_Property_of_Interest__c == null) {
                  //  If no Lead Property of Interest then create task, assign to PC Coordinator
                    **ld.Leasing_Agent__c = 'Prospect Coordinators';**  

                }
```

Comment: What it the problem?

Comment: i want to set the prospect coordinator name to leasing agent field if the Lead property of interest field is null .. when new lead is created.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had done this trigger using the id of the picklist values and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your trigger, a before insert trigger, won't have access to any lead.id fields.  They don't exist until the after insert trigger.

Assuming the code snippet is all you need to do, then it can be simplified to:

```
trigger enhanceLead on Lead (before insert) {
   for (Lead l :Trigger.new)
     if (l.create_leasing_call_task__c)
        l.leasing_agent__c = l.property_of_interest__c == null
           ? 'Prospect Coordinators'
           : l.leasing_agent__c;
}
```

Changes to Trigger.new are implicitly saved to the database

Comment: in Lead object i have tow fields Leasing_Agent__c and Lead_Property_Of_Interest__c now i want to set the when the Lead_Property_Of_Interest__c = null at that time Leasing_Agent__c is "Prospect Coordinators" but i am enable to set when new lead is generate in salesforce..

Comment: my trigger should do that; if I don't understand, you'll need to be more specific by EDITING your original question perhaps with an example as to what is not working